# Doing recursion by anonymous function

Tags: javascript

Hear is my code. I need to done the job without using a function name. 
Although functions cannot be named, they can be passed as parameters to another function.

And I dont want to use arguments.callee.

Can any one help me.

Actually its my task to do. that I need to do recursion in anonymous function. and I cant use any function name. but I can pass the function name as parameter to another function.
Is there any way to replace arguments.callee.

```
 var n=5; // The result should be 15
  console.log((function sum(n) {
      if (n ==0)
        return n;
      else
        return n + sum(n-1);
    })(n));
```

Comment: Naming the function is the right way to do it, why wouldn't you want to name it? Otherwise, as an exercise, consider using a Y combinator.

Comment: It might help if you would add some explanation as to *why* you don't want to give the function a name.

Comment: Actually its my task to do. that I need to do recursion in anonymous function. and I cant use any function name. but I can pass the function name as parameter to another function.

Answer (score 3):

You can wrap the code in an anonymous function, inside it you can declare a named function:

```
console.log((function(n){

  function fib(n) {
    if (n == 0) {
      return n;
    } else {
      return n + fib(n - 1);
    }
  }

  return fib(n);

})(n));
```

---

If you want to do that entirely without named functions, only setting a name to a function by passing it as a parameter, then you have to send the function reference along in every call:

```
console.log((function(f, n){

  return f(f, n);

})(function(f, n) {
  if (n == 0) {
    return n;
  } else {
    return n + f(f, n - 1);
  }
}, n));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the U-combinator:

```
const U = f => f(f);
const sum = n => n === 0 ? n : n + sum(n - 1);
const sum_ = U(h => n => n === 0 ? n : n + h(h)(n - 1));

sum(5); // 15
sum_(5); // 15
```

Notice how the passed lambda (anonymous function) has to be adapted in order to work with `U`:

```
     n => n === 0 ? 1 : n + sum (n - 1) // named
h => n => n === 0 ? 1 : n + h(h)(n - 1) // anonymous
```

Answer (score 0):

The only other option you have is to store the function in a variable.

```
var fib = function(n) { ... };
```

One way or another you must reference the function. If it's not a named and you don't use arguments.callee then you must store the reference in a variable.

Comment: Is there any thing new that replaces arguments.callee.. As its deprecated.