# Self execute function odd behaviour?

Tags: javascript

I have this self execute function that call itself:

```
(function a(x){
    if(x > 0){
        x--;
        console.log(x);
    }
    a(x);
})(5);
//outputs 4 3 2 1 0
```

This is correct behaviour . But if i pass this function to a variable how i can achieve the same behaviour?

```
var a = (function (x){
    if(x > 0){
        x--;
        console.log(x);
    }
    //a(x); outputs error
})(5);
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure `a` is undefined at this point (and always will btw)

Comment: Your IIFE returns nothing, so `a` is `undefined`

Comment: Here **a** is not a function, but holds return value of function that is undefined

Comment: possible duplicate of [javascript: recursive anonymous function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3883780/javascript-recursive-anonymous-function)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the second case, the result of your [Immediately Invoked Function Expression](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/) (IIFE), which will be `undefined`, is assigned to the variable `a`. Thus, `a` does not have a function associated with it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is possible to achieve the same result with my first example?

Comment: Why don't you just create a function? Or assign a function expression to `a`? e.g. `var a = function a(x) { return x+1; };`

Comment: var a =function(x){
    if(x > 0){
        x--;
      alert(x);
    }
    a(x);
};
a(5);