# Javascript - Recursive call

Tags: javascript, recursion, arguments

If there is a recursive call to be made in Javascript, there are basically 2 ways to do it. First way being -

```
function a() {
a();
}
```

and second way -

```
function a() {
arguments.callee();
}
```

Questions - 1) Its given in many places that 2nd way is better than 1st, but there is no explanation.

2) Arguments.callee being deprecated, what is the alternative?

3) Is there a way to call a self invoked function recursively, and that too with the function being anonymous. like given below, without using arguments.callee or any other function inside it.

```
console.log((function() {
//Recursive call...how?
})()
);
```

Comment: Where did you read that the 2nd way is better? As for Question 2, you already listed an alternative.

Comment: possible duplicate of [javascript: recursive anonymous function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3883780/javascript-recursive-anonymous-function)

Comment: I did not get the answer from both above comments

Answer (score 1):

1) Unless there's a good technical reason for this (you said you read this in many places but didn't give any references) I find the first way much better as it's more clear.

2) The alternative is exactly what you called the "first way".

3) You already solved the problem giving a name to the function so it's not anonymous anymore:

```
console.log((function a() {
    a();
})());
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, question 3 has been edited. pls see it.

Comment: @kushalbhandari Why don't you just give the function a name? I really don't understand the arbitrary requirement you're adding. It seems like an unnecessary complication.

Comment: @tnw - Its a question that i got from a puzzle :)

Comment: @kushalbhandari http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3883780/javascript-recursive-anonymous-function

Comment: @tnw - Other than adding a function inside it, or calling it using arguments.callee, did not find any other way.

Comment: @kushalbhandari Yeah, I haven't found anything else either. The answer might just be that there is no way to do specifically what you're asking.