# Crockford's Javascript Applicative Order Y Combinator syntax construct explanation?

Tags: javascript

Wanted to understand what syntax construct do / Find appropriate documentation covering the subject.

Was reading Crockford's The Little JavaScripter at https://www.crockford.com/little.html

I took a liberty to reformat code a little to point out the place where I get confused.

Note: It is too easy to wrongly format this piece of code, parser insertions can get in the way of execution and render factorial not valid function (perhaps that deserves whole new question)

```
function Y(le) {
    // just one return
    return (
        // ok, so far it returns a function
        function (f) { return f(f); }
        // here it starts to be syntaxically puzzling
        // what does following part, after already returning 
        // the function do?
        // construct looks like 'return ( f1(x) (f2 (x)) )'... 
        // looks very lispy
        (function (f) { 
            return le(function (x) { 
                return f(f)(x); 
            } ); 
        } )
    );
}

var factorial = Y(function (fac) {
    return function (n) {
        return (
            n <= 2
            ? n
            : n * fac(n - 1)
        );
    };
});

var number120 = factorial(5);
document.write(number120);
```

I am aware of so called IIFE syntax construct 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE
but construct used here is not really following IIFE (as far as I understand IIFE). This is kind of upside down construct and looks like it is some other kind of function construct recently introduced to JavaScript, but I cannot find the part of the documentation that covers this use. Is there a term covering this construct like there is IIFE (so I can search by the term).

Links to documentation are welcome.

Comment: the code inside `return (` is an IIFE ...

Comment: Now I got it. It is 'return ( function (f) /definition/ ...... () / immediate execution/ )' Thank you very much!

Comment: just for kicks ... here's the code in modern javascript `const Y = le => (f => f(f))(f => le((x) => f(f)(x)));` and `const factorial = Y(fac => n => n <= 2 ? n : n * fac(n - 1));` :p

Comment: Syntax in crockford's is still a bit different than MDN IIFE example. But I guess it is a specific IIFE variant is used here. Hence my confusion. Specifically instead of `(function () { statements })();` it is `(function () { statements } ( farg ))`. This is a reason why I did not recognize it as IIFE construct. Unless of course it is yet something else.

Answer (score 1):

This *is* an IIFE. It might he more clear if we format it as:

```
  return (function (f) { return f(f); })(
    function (f) { 
        return le(function (x) { 
            return f(f)(x); 
        }
    }
 });
```

Comment: IIFE example on MDN do not explicitly mention execution part to have expression in it. But obviously it can have it (just did not ponder this as use case). Its hard to format this so that it works and in the same hints structure that is easy to follow. Perhaps when IIFE becomes more common it will be easier to spot.

Comment: Kindly fix the syntax of the example.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of reverse engineering Crockford's `Y`, perhaps it's better to understand `Y` beginning with its purpose first. It's when we start with an intention and work our way *forward* to a solution that we can begin to understand how `Y` works.

***"I want to write a recursive formula... without using recursion"***

This was a problem facing mathematicians and logicians long before people had widespread access to computers. And this is the problem the `Y` combinator solves, but how does it do it? Let's first start with a recursive "formula" we want to write -

```
const fact = n =>
  n <= 2
    ? n
    : n * fact (n - 1) // <-- recursive!
```

Above `fact` is defined in terms of itself. We can remove this self-reference by using an extra parameter to control recursion, `recur` -

```
const fact =          n =>
const fact = recur => n =>
  n <= 2
    ? n
    : n * fact (n - 1)
    : n * ...  (n - 1)
```

But what should `recur` be? And how do we fill in `...`? Meet `U`. `U` simply applies a function to itself -

```js
const U = f =>
  f (f)                     // <-- apply f to itself

const fact = recur => n =>
  n <= 2
    ? n
    : n * U (recur) (n - 1) // <-- apply recur to itself

console.log (U (fact) (5))  // <-- apply fact to itself
// 120
```

Above we call `U (fact) (5)` to compute the result. It's important to observe that we could've applied `U` when we defined `fact = ...` -

```js
const U = f =>
  f (f)

const fact = U (recur => n => // <-- apply U directly on lambda
  n <= 2
    ? n
    : n * U (recur) (n - 1))

console.log (fact (5)) // <-- call fact normally
// 120
```

Using `U`, we now have a generic way to write recursive expressions -

```
U (recur => ...      U (recur) ...)
```

---

***"I don't like that I have to remember to use `U (recur) (...)`. Can I just call `recur (...)` instead?"***

`U` is an extremely simple mechanism, but indeed it is a little cumbersome because we have to remember to "reflect" `recur` back onto itself each time we recur. And this is where the `Y` combinator differs from the `U`. `Y` says,

- Give me function `f`, that's asking for a recursion mechanism
- I'll give you a recursion mechanism, `x => ...`, and when you call it, I will handle passing `x` to some `U (recur) (...)`

```js
const Y = f =>
  f (x => ...) // <-- instead of f (f)...
```

Just like we saw with `fact` above, we can write a recursive expression using `U` -

```
U (recur => ...      U (recur) ...)
```

So `Y` of some function `f`, will create a recursion mechanism, `U (recur => ...)` and it will call `f` with a function, `x => ...`, that when applied, will recur with `x` using `U (recur) (x)` -

```
const Y = f =>
  //            f (x =>    ...    (x))
  //            =======           ====
  //               |               |
  //               v               v
  // U (recur => ...    U (recur) ...)

     U (recur => f (x => U (recur) (x)))
```

Let's see `Y` in action below -

```js
const U = f =>
  f (f)

const Y = f =>
  U (recur => f (x => U (recur) (x)))

const fact = Y (recur => n =>
  n <= 2
    ? n
    : n * recur (n - 1)) // <-- call "recur" normally

console.log (fact (5)) // <-- call "fact" normally
// 120
```

---

**tomato, tomahto**

Crockford calls the `Y`-combinator *"...one of the most strange and wonderful artifacts of Computer Science"*, but I think that's because he doesn't understand it and continues to copy/paste the same `Y` examples you see around the internet. There's nothing *strange* about it unless you write it in such a way that obfuscates all meaning -

```
// replace IIFE with U
function Y(le) {
  return (
    function (f) { return f(f); }
    U
    (function (f) { 
      return le(function (x) { 
        return f(f)(x);
        return U(f)(x) 
      }); 
    })
  )
}

// remove unnecessary outer (...)
function Y(le) {
  return U(function (f) { 
    return le(function (x) { 
      return U(f)(x)
    })
  })
}

// simplified arrow expression
const Y = le =>
  U (f => le (x => U (f) (x))

// alpha rename "f" to "recur"
const Y = le =>
  U (recur => le (x => U (recur) (x))

// alpha rename "le" to "f"
const Y = f =>
  U (recur => f (x => U (recur) (x))
```

Which matches our version of `Y` above -

```
const Y = f =>
  U (recur => f (x => U (recur) (x)))
```

---

**without U**

We can expand `U` such that `Y` has a standalone definition -

```
// starting with 
const Y = f =>
  U (recur => f (x => U (recur) (x)))

// expand inner U
const Y = f =>
  U (recur => f (x => recur (recur) (x)))

// expand outer U
const Y = f =>
  (recur => f (x => recur (recur) (x)))
  (recur => f (x => recur (recur) (x)))
```

We're back to an IIFE, but this time our definition more closely matches Haskell Curry's [original definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_combinator) -

```js
const Y = f =>
  (recur => f (x => recur (recur) (x)))
  (recur => f (x => recur (recur) (x)))

const fact = Y (recur => n =>
  n <= 2
    ? n
    : n * recur (n - 1))

console.log (fact (5))
// 120
```

---

**expanding our `Y` intuition**

Like almost all other `Y` tutorials out there, Crockford demonstrates using `Y` on a function with a single argument. There's a lot of potential lurking just beyond these preliminary understandings of `Y`. I'll show you simple functions that take 2 or even 3 arguments -

```js
const Y = f =>
  (recur => f (x => recur (recur) (x)))
  (recur => f (x => recur (recur) (x)))

const range1 = Y (recur => m => n =>
  m > n
    ? []
    : [ m, ...recur (m + 1) (n) ])

const range2 = Y (recur => r => m => n => 
  m > n
    ? r
    : recur ([ ...r, m ]) (m + 1) (n)) ([])

const fib = Y (recur => a => b => n =>
  n === 0
    ? a
    : recur (b) (a + b) (n - 1)) (0) (1)

console.log (range1 (5) (10))
// [ 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 ]

console.log (range2 (5) (10))
// [ 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 ]

console.log (fib (10))
// 55
```

There's really no limit to the complexity of program that `Y` can express -

```
const Y = f =>
  (recur => f (x => recur (recur) (x)))
  (recur => f (x => recur (recur) (x)))

const reduce = Y (recur => i => f => state => a =>
  i >= a.length
    ? state
    : recur (i + 1) (f) (f (state, a[i])) (a)) (0)

const filter = f =>
  reduce ((r, x) => f (x) ? [ ...r, x ] : r) ([])

const odds =
  filter (n => n & 1)

console.log (odds ([ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ]))
// [ 1, 3, 5 ]
```

Comment: Related: see [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46821023/633183) for an explanation of `Y` using a mirror analogy.

Comment: How nice! Although I got the idea on the general problem that this code attempt to solve before, it is nice to have such elaborated explanation of the concept. My only comment (an that is not on Y-combinator) is that if language allows passing a function as argument then it is very likely that it already have recursion as mechanism natively. On the other hand if language does not have recursion in its design, it is slim chance that it also has function arguments (or what authors say first class functions). Nevertheless there is much more value in this answer on learning side of computing.

Answer (score 0):

My confusion was created by not understanding that:

```
var x = (function (a) {return a})(1);
var y = (function (a) {return a} (2));
var z = function (a) {return a} (3);
```

are all IIFE variants of the same kind. At least all 3 are recognized and executed in the same fashion (in the modern browser). MDN needs to clarify this.

MDN explain IIFE is in the form x

Crockford's example uses variant y.