# Recursion with function declaration JS

Tags: javascript, recursion, javascript-function-declaration

There are many questions about recursion with function expressions. And there are two ways to do it: One is using **named function expression** and second is using `arguments.callee`. But at this time `arguments.callee` is deprecated.

The question is what about recursion with function *declaration*. How can we remove `arguments.callee` from this example and not be depended on the function name.

```
function fib(n){
   return n < 3 ? 1 : arguments.callee(n - 1) + arguments.callee(n - 2);
}
```

Comment: The function is called "fib", so just call `fib(n - 1)` etc. Why don't you want to depend on the function name?

Comment: @Pointy In that way, I will can't copy that function and be sure that it will work. And in general, I think that functionality must not be dependent on the function name.

Comment: Yes, it's true that it is *possible* that the value of the symbol "fib" in the closure could be changed; if that's important, then the function can be declared as a function expression instead.

Comment: Can I come to the conclusion that recursion is better to do with Function Expression in any case?

Comment: Well in the case of function *expressions* you're guaranteed that unless the name is redefined in the function itself the name will definitely always refer to the function itself. In practical terms I don't think it's a big deal, but that's just me.

Comment: ok, thanks for the discussion.

Answer (score 2):

For function declarations there is no built-in mechanism to have safe self-reference. If the function is renamed, then using the name inside the body would be lead to an error

```js
function fib_renamed(n){
   return n < 3 ? 1 : fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2);
// used to be correct ^^^          ^^^
}

console.log(fib(8));
```

And [`arguments.callee`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments/callee) throws an error in strict mode:

```js
function fib(n){
  "use strict";
   return n < 3 ? 1 : arguments.callee(n - 1) + arguments.callee(n - 2);
}

console.log(fib(8));
```

However, any recursive function can be made name-agnostic with [the Y combinator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/93526/what-is-a-y-combinator) (also called [fixed-point combinator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_combinator)). Put simply it allows for a function to call itself without needing to have a formal name. In some languages it might not be possible for a function to refer to itself. In others, like JavaScript, it can. However, you can still leverage the Y/fixed-point combinator to avoid *having* to do that.

The function would need to be transformed to take one parameter which will be itself and then returns a function that uses said parameter for recursive calls. It is a bit more obvious if shown as an arrow function:

```javascript
//original
const fib = n => n < 3 ? 1 : fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2);
// calls itself              ^^^          ^^^

//updated
const updated = fib => 
//              ^^^ takes a function to call as parameter
             n => n < 3 ? 1 : fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2);
// calls the parameter        ^^^          ^^^
```

While using function declarations it will be

```javascript
//original
function fib(n){
   return n < 3 ? 1 : fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2);
}

//updated
function updated(fib) {
//               ^^^---->---->---->----->----->---+
  return function (n){//                          |
  //             ^ no name needed                 v
    return n < 3 ? 1 : fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2);// |
  }//                  ^^^----------^^^-----<-----+
}
```

The implementation of the Y combinator itself  is

```javascript
const Y  = f => (g => g (g)) (g => f (x => g (g) (x)));
```

(from ["Common combinators in JavaScript" by Avaq on GitHub](https://gist.github.com/Avaq/1f0636ec5c8d6aed2e45))

And the usage is:

```js
const Y = f => (g => g (g)) (g => f (x => g (g) (x)));

function updated(fib) {
  return function (n){
    return n < 3 ? 1 : fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2);
  }
}

console.log(Y(updated)(8));
//          ^^^^^^^^^^

//also possible:
const fib_new = Y(updated);
console.log(fib_new(8));
```

Comment: I think the final snippet would be much clearer if you didn't include the unnecessary `function fib(n) { ... }` and the calls to it.  Just use `updated`, `Y`, and `fib_new`.

Comment: @ScottSauyet thank you for the feedback. I agree - I've removed it. At the time of writing I thought it was going to show the result is the same but upon review it only takes up space.

Comment: Of course, you could always just skip `updated` altogether and use `const fib_new = Y((fib) => (n) => n < 3 ? 1 : fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2))` but that may be a step too far.

Comment: @ScottSauyet true but wanted to focus on the invocation of `Y` itself, hence I prefer it as short as possible. I figured inlining the function is trivial enough.

Comment: Nice answer. I added a supplement because I think U combinator is the essential focal point. It exists here as unnamed `(g => g(g))` in your code. Y has nicer ergonomics, but I think its approachability suffers beginners.

Answer (score 2):

**U combinator**

By passing a function to itself as an argument, a function can recur using its parameter instead of its name! So the function given to U should have at least one parameter that will bind to the function (itself).

```js
const U = f => f(f)
  
U(a => console.log(a))

// output:
// a => console.log(a)
```

1. `f` is assigned to `a => console.log(a)` and `U` calls `f(f)`
2. when `f` runs, it logs its only parameter `a` to the console
3. as we know, `a` *is* `f`
4. ie, `f` knows itself by means of `a`, without `arguments.callee` or name

Here's a minimal, terminating program -

```js
const U = f => f(f)

const countDown = recur => x =>
  x == 0
    ? "blast off!"
    : x + ", " + U(recur)(x - 1)
    
const ans =
  U(countDown)(10)
  
console.log(ans)
// 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, blast off!
```

Of course it works in the case where `arguments.callee` or the function's name would be referenced more than once. Take the classic `fib` example -

```js
const U = f => f(f)

const fib = recur => x =>
  x < 2
    ? x
    : U(recur)(x - 1) + U(recur)(x - 2)

const ans =
  U(fib)(10)
  
console.log(ans) // 55
```

By use of [currying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying), you can easily construct functions with more parameters -

```js
const U = f => f(f)

const range = recur => min => max =>
  min == max
    ? []
    : [min, ...U(recur)(min + 1)(max)]
    
const fold = recur => init => f => xs =>
  xs.length == 0
    ? init
    : U(recur)(f(init,xs[0]))(f)(xs.slice(1))

const add = (x, y) =>
  x + y

const numbers =
  U(range)(7)(14)
  
const sum =
  U(fold)(0)(add)(numbers)
  
console.log(numbers, sum)
// [7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]
// 70
```

**U** is the primordial essence from which the more sophisticated **Y** combinator is derived. See [this related Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43195580/633183) for more.

Comment: Beautiful... as always.  Perhaps we should see about getting this added to https://gist.github.com/Avaq/1f0636ec5c8d6aed2e45.

Comment: You can see it in-lined on line 12 where **Y** is defined, `g => g(g)`. I agree it's surprising not to see it on the list already, given its significance. http://www.ucombinator.org has a cute write-up at the bottom.