# Trying to make recursive solution fully functional

Tags: python, recursion, functional-programming

I am currently doing a recursive problem and I solved it. Now I want to make the solution fully functional by replacing the for loop with a helper function but I can't quite wrap my head around that. I am pretty sure it is done with a helper function that loops over the list by calling itself recursively and slicing the list after every item but I can't seem to have any luck. Any tips?

```
def flatten(arr):
    result = []
    for item in arr:
        if type(item) != type([]):
            result = result + [item]
        else:
            result = result + flatten(item)
    return result

print(flatten([1,[[2],3],[[[4]]]]))
##[1,2,3,4]
```

Comment: what type is arr?

Comment: @IgnacioAlorre I updated the question for clarification

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2170065/1491895

Comment: @IgnacioAlorre I want to implement it myself with my own functions so I understand everything better.

Comment: @Barmar, you are right

Comment: @Barmar I would agree that this is a poor duplicate as  it answers a question the OP quite clearly shows he has already answered.

Comment: I don't know but I almost solve this with `print(list(map(lambda item: result + [item] if type(item) != type([]) else result + flatten(item), arr)))` and then I realized the lambda needs to call itself. I'm not smart enough to understand the techniques for getting a lambda to call itself https://stackoverflow.com/questions/481692/can-a-lambda-function-call-itself-recursively-in-python

Comment: I did read it fully. Most of the answers in that question use a loop, but one of them is functional as he requests. @user737163

Comment: I put a link to that answer in my comment.

Comment: @user737163 My comment about flattening only one level was in response to someone else's comment.

Comment: The answer I linked to is recursive.

Comment: The code of the OP is recursive.

Comment: The solution linked is indeed functional, you are correct @Barmar.

Comment: @MatthewMartin [recursive lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43195580/633183) or _anonymous recursion_ is not as challenging as you might think! Such a technique makes recursion possible even where recursion by name is not supported. Note, the `x => ...` arrows functions from JavaScript are equivalent to Python's `lambda x: ...` functions,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use mathematical induction -

1. if input `t` is empty, return the base case, `[]`
2. (induction) `t` is not empty. if the first element in `t` is a list, flatten it and combine it with the flattened sub-problem `t[1:]`
3. (induction) `t` is not empty and the first element in `t` is not a list. return the first element in `t` and the flattened sub-problem, `t[1:]`

```py
def flatten(t):
  if not t:
    return []                             # 1
  elif isinstance(t[0], list):
    return flatten(t[0]) + flatten(t[1:]) # 2
  else:
    return [t[0]] + flatten(t[1:])        # 3

print(flatten([1,[[2],3],[[[4]]]]))
```

```py
[1,2,3,4]
```

Which is the same as this, using `*` spread operator -

```py
def flatten(t):
  if not t:
    return []                                   # 1
  elif isinstance(t[0], list):
    return [ *flatten(t[0]), *flatten(t[1:]) ]  # 2
  else:
    return [ t[0], *flatten(t[1:]) ]            # 3
```

Another option is to describe a new sub-problem in branch `2`. Instead of

1. flatten the first element, `t[0]`, as `x`
2. flatten the rest of the list, `t[1:]`, as `y`
3. combine, `x + y`

A different sub-problem could look like this -

1. combine the first element, `t[0]`, with the rest of the list, `t[1:]`, as `x`
2. flatten `x`

```py
def flatten(t):
  if not t:
    return []                         # 1
  elif isinstance(t[0], list):
    return flatten(t[0] + t[1:])      # 2 <-
  else:
    return [ t[0], *flatten(t[1:]) ]  # 3
```

Or consider using generators -

```py
def flatten(t):
  if not t:
    return                       # 1
  elif isinstance(t[0], list):
    yield from flatten(t[0])     # 2
    yield from flatten(t[1:])    # 2
  else:
    yield t[0]                   # 3
    yield from flatten(t[1:])    # 3

print(list(flatten([1,[[2],3],[[[4]]]])))
```

```py
[1,2,3,4]
```

Or use generic functionals like `flatmap` -

```py
def reduce(f, init, t):
  if not t:
    return init
  else:
    return reduce(f, f(init, t[0]), t[1:])

def flatmap(f, t):
  return reduce \
    ( lambda r, v: r + f(v)
    , []
    , t
    )

def flatten(t):
  return flatmap \
    ( lambda v: \
        flatten(v) if isinstance(v, list) else [v]
    , t
    )

print(flatten([1,[[2],3],[[[4]]]]))
```

```py
[1,2,3,4]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make it work along the following lines, using [`functools.reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce):

```
from functools import reduce

def reducer(a, b):
    return a + (flatten(b) if isinstance(b, list) else [b])

def flatten(arr):
    return reduce(reducer, arr, [])

>>> flatten([1,[[2],3],[[[4]]]])
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```